# Deleted value in trigger MySQL in WHERE statement?

Tags: mysql, triggers

I want to do simple trigger on delete in table X which will change value in table Table which has the same id.

```
UPDATE Table T  
SET T.spots = T.spots +1
Where T.id = delete.id
```

But it doesnt work. I am not sure if "delete.*columnName*" works.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned by [fejese](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1565862/fejese) in the comments, use

```
UPDATE Table T  
SET T.spots = T.spots +1
Where T.id = OLD.id -- Use OLD.id instead of delete.id
```